# Laravel, how to sort and paginate of loop array

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code in controller, so I need to paginate and sort by using distance, I dont know how to do this, Im new to laravel , thanks in advance

```
$stores = [];
foreach (session('storeinfo') as $storeInfo) {
$store = Storeinfo::find($storeInfo['id']);
if ($store) {
    $store->distance = $storeInfo['distance'];
    $stores[] = $store;

 $stores = collect([]);

 if (!Collection::hasMacro('paginate')) {
Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage = 25, $page = null, $options = []) {
    $options['path'] = $options['path'] ?? request()->path();
    $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
    return new LengthAwarePaginator(
        $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->values(),
        $this->count(),
        $perPage,
        $page,
        $options
    );
    });   
   }
  }
 }

return view('stores.archive',compact('stores'));
```

Im placing id into session using this:

```
 $allstores= Storeinfo::all();
foreach ($allstores as $allstore) {
Session::push('storeinfo', [
'id' => $allstore->id,
'distance' => $miles
]);  

}}
```

where $mile comes from calculation of distance
    enter code here

Comment: `Model::find(...` is typically used for finding a single item(row) in a table. Pagination doesn't apply to a single item. Can you provide more context to your problem? How are you placing storeinfo items into session? Is `$storeInfo['id']` a foreign key? I'm assuming you have a Store to StoreInfo model relationship, if so, the code in these models will be useful here.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would create a collection instance of your `$stores` array:

```
$stores = collect([]);
```

I prefer using the `push()` api of the collection to add items:

```
$stores->push($store);
```

Second, the collection instance doesn't provide a native way to paginate so you need to add a macro:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator; 
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;

...

if (!Collection::hasMacro('paginate')) {
    Collection::macro('paginate', function ($perPage = 25, $page = null, $options = []) {
        $options['path'] = $options['path'] ?? request()->path();
        $page = $page ?: (Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1);
        return new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $this->forPage($page, $perPage)->values(),
            $this->count(),
            $perPage,
            $page,
            $options
        );
    });
}
```

I personally added the above macro in `AppServiceProvider` so that I can use it anywhere in my project. This should be located in the `app/Providers` directory.

To paginate you simply need to call the `paginate()` macro you just created:

```
$stores->paginate(15);
```

If you wish to set the current page or path, you may do so:

```
$stores->paginate(15, 1, ['path' => 'your/custom/path']);
```

To sort, all you need to do is used the desired [sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby) method to achieve your results.

Per the docs, `sortBy` takes a string:

```
$sorted = $collection->sortBy('price');
```

Or a callback:

```
$sorted = $collection->sortBy(function ($product, $key) {
    return count($product['colors']);
});
```

The method, `sortByDesc()` works the same way as `sortBy()`.

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Collection' not found

Comment: add a use statement to the top of your controller: `use Illuminate\Support\Collection`. If you use the helper you shouldn't need this.

Comment: are you getting into your conditional: `if ($store) {`?

Comment: You are now reassigning `$stores`. This is why it is empty. You only need to do `$stores = collect([]);` once. Where you had it originally before your `foreach`.

Comment: I added {!! $stores->links() !!} in the blade but it says Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist.

Comment: You need to paginate `$stores`: `return view('stores.archive', ['stores' => $stores->paginate(15)]);`

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Paginator' not found

Comment: You need to add a use statement for classes that don't exist in your working namespace: `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;`

Comment: after use paginatior it says Class 'App\Http\Controllers\LengthAwarePaginator' not found

Comment: now it shows the error in the blade Undefined variable: stores

Comment: its working fine now im working to show the number of pages down the blade

Comment: in the number of pages the link is duplicated like this: /store/caterer_search/store/caterer_search/ so have to remove one store/caterer_search/ how can  I do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197227/discussion-between-ash-and-adam).

Comment: in the number of pages the link is duplicated like this: /store/caterer_search/store/caterer_search/ so have to remove one store/caterer_search/ how can I do this?

Comment: $stores->setPath('' . $searchfilter);
Thank you its working fine now :)

Comment: Updated answer.